# Side by Side Grids

Tags: html, css, json, html-table, gridjs

How could I approach the following ...

I have a dataset, lets say it has 75 rows

I would like this data to be displayed in a grid, the first 25 rows in the left hand grid and then next 25 rows in the right hand grid ... then pagination would indicate that there was a second page and when moving to that page I would see 25 records in the left hand grid and nothing in the right hand grid

The rows on the left would align with the rows on the right and the grids would take up 100% of the height and 50% of the width each

Ideas?

TIA

Chris.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you should start with a carousel/slider, where each slide contains a table or grid, and build up from there. It won't guarantee alignment between the rows on each page though, unless you make the rows a fixed height.